# Server to Cydia Tweak/App notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, cydia

I have spent an hour or so scanning around the web trying to find some sort of push library for Cydia tweaks/apps. Basically, I want to notify the cydia tweak I am building of a particular event and then have the tweak respond.

As I understand, there is no way to integrate with APNS (despite having a dev account). So, I am looking for a 3rd party solution - if there is one!

Please let me know if you know of a solution. Thanks :)

Comment: Did you find anything?